# not able to find master database under azure SQL server (dw)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am trying to scale Azure SQLDW by following this document => [azure link](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/quickstart-scale-compute-tsql) but help guide says, to run query under master DB.

I am logging in using system admin credential, 
[image: admin credential]

[image: error while running query.]

what am i missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the first screen shot, it appears that you've connected to the user database and not the server with the default database. When connecting to your server in SSMS, click on the **Connection Properties** tab and make sure the **Connect to database:** value is set to *<default>*.

[Connection Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhrti.png)

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL DW  master DB is the same with Azure SQL Server.

Please run the query in `Database`--`System Database`--`master`.

Login your Azure SQL DW with admin account,  set the connect to  database.
**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

**Step3**

[image]

Hope this helps.